# Is there a way to quickly jump to, say, the 15th page?

Tags: support, user-interface

Right now on the bottom of the page only page 1-5 and the last page has a hyperlink button. When I want to go to, say, the 15th page, I have to click on the 5th page, then keep pressing next page until I reaches the 15th page. Are there are faster way?

May be there isn't a button there. Are there some ways where I can reflect this suggestion to StackExchange so that they can add that option?

Comment: Edit the address bar in your browser. Append `?page=15`, perhaps `?page=15&sort=active` or whatever criterion you want to sort by.

Comment: Oh thanks haven't thought of this way. That's solves my problem

Comment: Is there a quick way to jump to, say, the 15th page from the end?

Comment: @GerryMyerson you can check the total number and subtract to get the correct number, which is reasonably possibly as the total number is displayed (and the last page accessible). I am not sure this qualifies as quick.

Comment: It's not about whether it's quick, it's about the trick

Answer (score 4):

Answered in the comments by Daniel Fischer:

> Edit the address bar in your browser. Append `?page=15`, perhaps `?page=15&sort=active` or whatever criterion you want to sort by.